# Getting Duplicates from two columns in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been looking at this all day. I am trying to return a list of duplicates from two columns in two separate tables.

In MYSQL the only way to get a full outer join seems to be with a UNION, which I have tried:

```
select mobile from firstTable
group by mobile
having count(mobile) > 1
union all
select mobile from secondTable
group by mobile
having count(mobile) > 1;
```

However, this gets duplicates in the same tables, and doesn't account for across table duplicates. I have also tried joins, however I don't know how to then check for duplicates across the separate columns?

My intent is to get duplicates as if both columns where 1 and I am counting those with multiple entries. Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Do you mean you want duplicate values that exists more one once, no matter if they are in just one of the tables - or, do you want duplicates that exist on both tables. For example once in t1 and once in t2?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I mean that exists more than once if treating both columns as a single. @jarlh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend taking a union first, then aggregating the combined result:

```
SELECT mobile
FROM
(
    SELECT mobile FROM firstTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT mobile FROM secondTable
) t
GROUP BY mobile
HAVING COUNT(mobile) > 1;
```

Note: If within each of the two tables, a given `mobile` value could appear more than once, then use `SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM some_table` to first remove the duplicates.

Comment: I had tried this method, but I had forgot to name the result of the inner select (in this case 't'), and assumed it was producing an error because a union wouldn't work inside a select. So that is something to remember!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner, this answer may help other beginners too in finding duplicates
I would try creating a view contains both columns to avoid any confusion

```
CREATE VIEW newTable as (SELECT T1.columnA, T2.columnB from table1 join table2 on T1.id=T2.id)
```

And then do the selection from this new table

`SELECT
    columnA, columnB, COUNT(*)
FROM
    newTable
GROUP BY
    A, B
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1`

The output should be the row that is duplicate in column A & column B together not in each individually like the following example:

T1 ( water bottles I have in the store) and T2 ( water bottles that have been bought) and say that I want to find how many water bottles do I have with same brand and how many times this brand was bought by this visa card particularly...
This is what I understand you trying to do
The output should this table
[image: picture]